# lex - Removing "/*" also removes internal stars

Tags: lex

I'm trying to pull comments out of a c file. But my code pulls out all stars instead of just /* and */. Can anyone help?

Input  `/**A**/` or `/***/`

Desired Output `*A*` and `*`

My Output `*A` and nothing

Code

```
"/*"    /* comment */ BEGIN(Comment);
<Comment>{
    [^*]         /* not a '*' */ ECHO;
    "*"+[^/]      /* '*'s not followed by '/' */ ECHO;
    "*"+"/"       /* end of Comment */ BEGIN(INITIAL);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last two patterns to

```
"*"+/[^/]
"*/"
```

Your last pattern explicitly takes every `*` at the end of the comment out of the comment. If you only change the last rule, then it will not recognize the end of the comment of for example `/***/`, because `/*` will start the comment, then `**` is matched by the one but last pattern and the `/` is matched by `[^*]`.

`"*"+/[^/]` matches all sequences of `*` followed by anything but a `/`, but not consuming the character that follows. This is necessary as this could be the `*` of the `*/` closing the comment.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. One more quick question. How would I skip a new line if there's two in a row \n\n. I tried something like `"\n"+/[^\n]   ECHO;` to only print the newline if it is not succeeded by another newline, but this didn't work, there was no change from `\n   ECHO;`. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd say just add the pattern `"\n"+ { printf("\n"); }`, not everything needs to be done with `ECHO`.

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches non-nesting C comments:

```
"/*"([^*]|[*]*[^*/])*"*"+"/"
```

Here is a complete Lex program which strips C comments from input, replacing each one with a space.

```
%%

"/*"([^*]|[*]*[^*/])*"*"+"/" putc(' ', yyout);

%%
```

However, this fails to provide helpful diagnostics.  For instance if something like `/*   /*   */` occurs, it's nice to generate a warning about a suspicious looking start of a comment within a comment. Also, if a comment is unterminated, it's useful to detect that and produce a diagnostic about were that diagnostic started.

For these reasons, it may be best to handle C comments by recognizing just the `/*` sequence and then taking over with a custom piece of code that reads characters from the `yyin` stream and recognizes the rest of the comment.